# How to read more than 400 meg excel in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel

How can I import that Excel file into SQL Server? I have more than 400 meg Excel file which has two sheets.

I want to know that if is there any way by which can I read it in chunks/parse it to csv and then import. I need to know if it can be done without using oledb or openxml or any other kind of automation tools.

I have checked the options with openxml and tried to send it to SQL Server but not getting enough luck, I have tried oledb but it seems like that oledb is having its own limitations.

Thanks

Comment: What's a `400 meg excel file`? Do you mean MB (megabytes)?

Comment: You can open it in Excel and save it as a CSV.  If that is not sufficient, then you will need to give us more information than "*tried to send it to sql but not getting enough luck*", which tells us nothing.

Comment: `without using ... any other kind of automation tools`, what do you think c# is?

Comment: MEG = MB, :) young it sucks when i open it it takes ages to open. i have tried to read this using oledb connection which fails on opening excel file using oledb open command.

Answer (score 2):

If you have sql server integration services or data tools installed you can use the Sql Server Wizard to "Import and Export Data". There you choose "Excel File" as Source, your Database as Destination and then you can define table and column mappings including the necessary data conversions. You can also define pre- and post-import sql commands (like drop and (re)create the table that you want to import the data into... or simply empty the table).

As soon as you have the whole import defined you can save a so-called SSIS (Sql Server Integration Service) - Package either into your database or into a file nested in your solution. That *.dtsx file can be opened with the "Sql Server Integration Services Package
Execution Utility" to automatically run the import.

So you could run the import at some time in your build-process or even start it in a background process. Just make sure you place your excel file where you've defined the source for the import to be.

If you have Visual Studio 12 and up, Sql Server Data Tools should be automatically installed. With those in place you can open up the *.dtsx files at any time in your Visual Studio and modify the import behaviour. I've only recently copied such a .dtsx-file because i need to import an excel file into 4 different staging databases, so for each database i just modified the corresponding copy of the .dtsx-file's database-connection-credentials.

Comment: SQL server reporting services is one of the option but I have light version of sql(localdb) is there any way by which I can import it like a flat file.

Comment: i don't think you can do it as a flat file... excel cells can hold data you can't easily convert into a CSV and with a 400MB file you probably don't want to convert the data manually before you import the file. I would suggest you just download and install sql server express and the management studio, use that to create and connect to a db and then in the sql server management studio right-click on your database and chose Task => Import Data... then you can import the excel file. you should be able to access that from your code to copy all to a localDB... havent worked much with localdb :-(

Comment: you if you want to keep your installation small you should be able to use Sql Server Compact Edition as http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403372(v=sql.105).aspx explains it can be used as destination for integration services

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at [python](http://www.python.org) + [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) - pandas has a method for reading from excel into pandas data frames, [read_exel()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel), and to write to your sql database, [to_sql()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_sql).

Comment: This question was tagged C#. I doubt Python solution is going to be wanted.